# iOS app becomes idle occasionally in background

Tags: ios, location, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an iOS app that uses the user location and a BLE connection to a bespoke device. In some use cases it needs to use them both while in background. When in background the app also writes some logs into a file for my own analysis.
Everything is working fine most of the times but occasionally my app get like "suspended" and doesn't produce any logs until it's brought back to foreground, at that point though, the app is simply resumed and the delegate method applicationWillEnterForeground is invoked.
I don't understand the reason for such "suspension", from my log analysis it seems to be happen more frequently (but not very consistently) when the BLE connection fails and the app fails to connect to the device but I was expecting that the app is kept active in background and keeps receiving (and logging) information about the user location plus some of my logic while this doesn't happen. My app just doesn't receive any event from CoreLocation or CoreBluetooth.

The fact that on manual foreground the app receives the applicationWillEnterForeground means that the app is not killed while in background for memory reasons as I originally thought.

This problem occurs with any iOS version (9, 10, 11)

Can anyone give me any hint on what should I look for?

Alessio

Comment: have you enabled and are you using either background or significant-change location services?

Comment: Does locking the device have any effect? (i.e. does it trigger the issue?) Also make sure you have the correct background mode set in the plist.

Comment: As I wrote, the background mode is set correctly and the app works fine when in background (it receives the location and reads/writes the BLE characteristic). The problem occurs only occasionally if the BLE connection is dropped for some radio interference. I do have a logic that detects the disconnection and attempt to reconnect to the BLE device.  If the device doesn't reply to the BLE connection for some time (about 20 secs) the app gets suspended and stop receiving also location updates.